# What is it called in everyday general English: a panel with prayers on it?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Look at the picture

[image]

This is a typical holy table in some Asian countries, there is a panel (which is normally made of wood) with prayers on it which is put between the Earth God & the Fortune God.

**What is a general term for it?**

Comment: The "holy table" is called an _altar_, but I'm not aware of a specific English word for the framed object.

Comment: What do you mean by "God words"? Is it similar to a prayer? Is it a religious law?  Is it a type of *blessing*? What do bi-lingual dictionaries say?

Comment: @Mari-LouA, yes, prayers make more sense. Generally, words for worship stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked for a *general term* to describe a piece of religious text placed on a shrine between the Chinese gods Tudigong and Caishen.

The text itself might be termed an *inscription*. As it is on a piece of wood, it may also be called an *engraving*.

Depending on the *content* of the inscription, there are some generic terms for religious texts such as a *prayer* (a speech directed to god), or a *blessing* (a request for favour from God, either for yourself or others). Words that are considered to be *from* God, either directly or indirectly, for example through a prophet, may be referred to as a *holy text* or *sacred text*. The word *scripture* is most commonly used to refer to excerpts from Christian writings, but by extension to any holy text.

The piece of wood itself might be called a *tablet*.

Comment: so, call it as "a tablet of prayers / holly text"?